# how do I use pre_built library

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

let say I have this piece of code:

print.cpp

```
int print ()
{
  return 10;
}
```

print.h

```
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H
int print(); // function prototype for add.h
#endif
```

I compiled into a library call libTest.a

now let say i have this android.mk file

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libtest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../issmlib/libTest.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

of course there is others thing like shared, but assumed they all work fine!!!
I put libTest.a in a folder called issmlib and it is in my project same level as jni folder
I then put print.h into a folder called include.

now this is my main:

```
#include "com_lan_factorial_FacLib.h"
#include "fac.h"

    //extern long fac(long n);

    JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_lan_factorial_FacLib_fac(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jlong n)
    {
        fac *f = new fac();
        jlong result = (jlong) (f->factorial(n));
        delete(f);
        return result + print();
    }
```

so what it does it compute the result and add 10 to it.
I do not know how to use that pre-built library, do i have to state #include "print.h"
I did put it in but it complains that no implementation of the method.
When I take it out, it complains that no print() have been declared.

This is much of a C++ question, but hopefully you can help. 
[image]

I believe my pathing for Android.mk is fine, but if you spot something wierd, please let me know.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have `V=1` parameter on the `ndk-build` command line. This way, you will see the actual compilation commands as the are prepared by ndk-build. This often gives a clue as to what is wrong with the path definitions in `Android.mk`.

If you need help interpreting this log, leave a comment here and edit the question to include the full build log and the full `Android.mk`, including the part that invokes **BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY**